# Am I utilizing chi-squared incorrectly?

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I have a frequency table with the following structure:

```
str(sample_table)
int[1:33,1:23]10000010..
-attr(*,"dimnames)=List of 2
..$Var1:chr[1:33] "City1","City2","City3","City4"...
..$Var2: chr [1:23] "personal veh", "personal veh", "public-bus"...
-attr(*,"class")=chr [1:2] "xtable" "table"
-attr(*,"call")= language xtabs (formula = Freq ~ Var` + Var2, data = sample_table)
```

Original data structure:
V1: "City1","City2","City3","City1", "City1", "City1", "City2","City2","City1"...
V2: "personal veh", "personal veh","public-bus","pesonal veh", "private-train"...

However, when running `summary`, the output results in:

```
Number of cases in table: 923
Number of factors: 2
Test for independence of all factors:
Chisq = 3557, df = 704, p-value = 0
```

Am I using the correlation testing incorrectly? I have attempted to establish the vars as numerical (through factorization) but that offers no help.

Goal: Determine whether or not there is a correlation between the city/town one visits and the vehicle used.

> Updating to show example of how multivars would look per city:

````
            Personal Veh    Private-taxi    Private-Uber    Public-Bus ....
City 1            1               1             0               1

```
````

Comment: Would it be correct to understand from the output that you have just 923 observations classified into $33\times 23=759$ categories?

Comment: Yes. At some locations, (33 variables) there were multiple selections:

For example, City 1 has selections for...

            PersonalVeh    Private-Taxi    Private-Uber    Public-Bus    Private-Oth
City 1          1                     1                     0                         0                1

Comment: What is the `Freq` variable?  I'm trying to figure out why the output of `summary` doesn't end with `Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect` and I suspect `Freq` might have something to do with that.

Comment: Freq var was formed by the creation of the xtable (which took vars City (V1) & Transportation Type (V2)) and performed a frequency distribution.